# Finding all the ICollectionView's attached to a collection

Tags: wpf, filtering, collections, collectionviewsource, icollectionview

We have multiple filters based on the same collection. i.e. we are displaying the same collection in a variety of ways. What i would like to be able to do is ask all of the CollectionViews to refresh when a property changes (as the collection view will only refilter if items get added/removed from the collection). Is there a way to find all the collectionViews associated with a given collection. Is there a two way link between the collection view and the collection, or a way to determine this link.

P.S. I dont think the answer is

```
ICollectionView coll = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Collection);
```

as this will give me the default view for the collection, not all of the ICollectionViews asscoiated with the Collection.

Comment: What kind of collection?

Comment: Observable, though i am using ListCollectionView which takes an IList as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your collection is an ObservableCollection, you can do a ResettableObservableCollection.

```
public class ResettableObservablecollection<T>: ObservableCollection<T>
{
   //copy desired ctors

   public void ForceReset()
   {
       OnCollectionChanged(new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
   }
}
```

The ICollectionView that gets generated will be watching for that and refresh itself.

Comment: that makes sense, i wonder what performance impact it would have if the collection view was bound to a grid with a thousand entries or so. I'll try this out Monday.